# Trigger event on sound input from mic

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to make an application that'll react when a sharp and loud sound will be heard in my tablets microphone.

What I want to know is if it's possible to trigger such an event and is it possible to set some sort of threshold for the sound level of the input.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check these links out:

- StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6116694/530933).
- Which leads to this [NoiseAlert source code](http://code.google.com/p/android-labs/source/browse/trunk/NoiseAlert/src/com/google/android/noisealert/SoundMeter.java?r=2).

But its just a matter of listening on the microphone then triggering your event when sound levels are high enough.

Comment: That satisfies the "loud" condition, but what about the "sharp"? nevero, are you looking to respond to a particular kind of sound, or just when it gets loud?