# How to trigger Vibration on Sound Input?

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder, vibration, android-vibration

I am trying to create an android application where I filter one specific frequency of a beep and make the phone vibrate.

I am taking input from the MIC of mobile and using MediaRecorder class, by using this class, I can record, save and play the input. Now I need my mobile to vibrate whenever there is a beep/or any sound.

The input is given by a wire to the Headphone jack of the mobile so I know that there is only one frequency being input.

I have a button, Clicking which starts recording.
I have Permissions to vibrate and record in my manifest file already.

```
record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    isRecording=true;
                    myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                    myAudioRecorder.start();
...
}
```

I also tried to search the internet and found kind of the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838970/trigger-event-on-sound-input-from-mic) but I am unable to find any correct answer.

However, I can make the phone vibrate on clicking another button and here is the snipt of code,

```
 Vibrator vibrate;
    vibrate = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        Btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                       vibrate.vibrate(800);
                                    }
                                }
```

I tried calling a Vibrator inside recorder.start(); function but this makes the phone vibrate even when there is no sound anymore.
I also tried getting help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145213/android-audio-capture-silence-detection) so whenever there is silence, the phone should not vibrate, but I am getting confused, I somehow understand that there should be a Boolean which gets true when there is sound and make the phone vibrate, but I am unable to put this logic into code.
Please let me know what can I do in this context and which direction should I be searching in?

**UPDATE**
I found [this](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000086) toturial for showing the progress bar with amplitude of input sound, it works fine and I tried to make the phone vibrate when there is some value in buffer, Now it vibrates even when the amplitude is zero, I guess thats because of the fact that every vibration makes noise which leads the phone to vibrate. I am unable to check the function via TOAST because of ***java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()***. Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

For your main problem, maybe you can check for the amplitude of the sound, and only vibrate if a minimum threshold has been reached. Something like this:

```
private class DetectAmplitude extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
    private final static int MAX_AMPLITUDE = 32768;
    //TODO: Investigate what is the ideal value for this parameter
    private final static int MINIMUM_REQUIRED_AVERAGE = 5000;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Boolean soundStarted = true;
        if (mRecorder == null) {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                soundStarted = false;
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not detect background noise. Error preparing recorder: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                soundStarted = false;
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not detect background noise. Error preparing recorder: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                mRecorder.start();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not detect background noise. Error starting recorder: " + e.getMessage());
                soundStarted = false;
                mRecorder.release();
                mRecorder = null;
            }
        }

        if (soundStarted) {
            // Compute a simple average of the amplitude over one
            // second
            int nMeasures = 100;
            int sumAmpli = 0;
            mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude(); // First call returns 0
            int n = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < nMeasures; i++) {
                if (mRecorder != null) {
                    int maxAmpli = mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
                    if (maxAmpli > 0) {
                        sumAmpli += maxAmpli;
                        n++;
                    }
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 / nMeasures);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;

            final float avgAmpli = (float) sumAmpli / n;

            if (avgAmpli > MINIMUM_REQUIRED_AVERAGE) {
                //TODO: Vibrate the device here
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

For more information regarding the detection of sound level, please refer to the following:

- [android: detect sound level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181449/android-detect-sound-level)
- [What does Android's getMaxAmplitude() function for the MediaRecorder actually give me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655703/what-does-androids-getmaxamplitude-function-for-the-mediarecorder-actually-gi)

Regarding the exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`, that is happening because the `Toast` needs to run on the main thread of your app. If your `Thread` code (like an `AsyncTask`) is inside an `Activity`, you can try the following:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Call your Toast here
        }
    });
```

Otherwise, you need to somehow pass the conclusion of your method to the `Activity` for it to run the `Toast`.

EDIT:

If you want to use this from a `Button`, you could set its `OnClickListener` on your `Activity`'s `onCreate()` call and execute the `AsyncTask` there. For example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DetectAmplitude().execute(new Void[]{});
        }
    });
}
```

I suggest you take a look at [how AsyncTask works](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) before using this in production code.

Comment: Hello, This sounds great but I am unable to find a way to start recording on the button click, would you suggest, a button onclicklistener method inside the AsyncTask and then the protected Void doInBackground(Void... params inside it?

Comment: Hi @MomoPomo I edited my answer with an usage example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You want to sample the audio, and analyze it immediately.

MediaRecorder seems to high level for this, it only captures to file. You probably want to use [AudioRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) instead, as it gives direct access to the input samples.

In order to detect a *specific tone*, you can use the [Goertzel algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) on the input samples. Here is a [C++ implementation](http://musicdsp.org/showone.php?id=107) I did years ago that could serve as an example.

In  order to detect any sound *over a certain threshold*, you can use [Root Mean Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) analysis on the input samples and make it trigger once the loudness reaches your threshold. Here is a [Python example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4160733/1666063) that reacts to loud noises from a microphone.

Comment: You can use `setOutputFile("/dev/null")` on the `MediaRecorder` to avoid the file output. Also,  for just detecting if there is noise, the media recorder would do just fine by checking the sound amplitude over a small period of time.

Comment: Your answer is great, but as I need to develop android and also several other beginners, it would have been great if only android implementations were introduced, however for taking the logic its excellent, still I had the logic already what I needed was syntax to implement it. Also for learning purposes its not necessary to change the used classes without implementing one thoroughly at first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    vibrate.vibrate(800);
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I need to make the phone vibrate when there is a sound, not on click, I already am able to do that. Please read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    Handler handler;
    Runnable r;

            handler = new Handler();
                r = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    vib.vibrate(500);
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

                    }
                };
            handler.post(r);
```

Comment: Would you please explain the code, I am new to android and not familiar with all the concepts.